# Cannot find the file containing $path

Tags: path, environment, enthought

If I type `echo $PATH` on my macbook's terminal, this is the output:

```
/Users/lkloh/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Users/lkloh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin:/Users/lkloh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/Users/lkloh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/Users/lkloh/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/lkloh/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pysmo-aimbat-0.1.2/scripts:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
```

However, if I do `vi .bash_profile`, this is what I get, and I can't remove the extra links i see in the path.

```
# Added by Canopy installer on 2014-05-04
# VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT can be set to '' to make bashprompt show that Canopy is     active, otherwise 1
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source     /Users/lkloh/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate
```

I did `vi .profile`, and it does not exist. I also did `.bash_rc`, and it does not exist. How can I find the file with the sym links I see in my $PATH variable? I want to delete some of them.

Comment: Check `/etc/profile`.

Comment: you can remove edits to your PATH directly in `.bash_profile`. If you're symlinks were created in homebrew, you can always unlink the item. I would start with editing your PATH.

Comment: I am trying to edit my path, but when i check my `.bash_profile`, those paths don't seem to be there. Where else can I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac OS X setting of environment variables, at the OS desktop level, is quite obscure. There are several useful links in the "Mac OS X" section of this article: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23665767-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-